# Netbeans GUI wont display

Tags: java, netbeans

I have designed a simple gui in netbeans on windows but when i try to run it,nothing is showing.My main class is called `ModelApp.java` and the gui part i designed in netbeans is called `app.java`. When i try running the jar on command prompt,i get the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ModelApp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ModelApp` class is probably not in the folder written in the manifest file or something like that.

See [JAR Basics](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html)

Comment: That was indeed the issue.If anyone else encounters the same problem,you can have a look at this: netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-functionality.html . It says 
Note: Make sure my.NumberAddition.NumberAdditionUI is set as the main class before running the application. You can check this by right-clicking the NumberAddition project node in the Projects pane, choosing Properties in the popup menu, and selecting the Run category in the Project Properties dialog box. The Main Class field should display my.numberaddition.NumberAdditionUI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run your application by clicking on the jar you need to specify the main class in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in the jar as it is described [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html/%22here%22%22) . Make sure you have it properly defined.

You should be able to do this in Netbeans during creation of your jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to create the main method in ModelApp.java?

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {
app gui = new app();
}
```

Normally this should work